# Undo a `raco pkg update --clone` or `raco pkg install --clone`

Tags: racket, raco

I frequently like to use `raco pkg install --clone` (or `raco pkg --update clone` if the library is already installed), when I want to work on a library and submit patches.

However, I accidentally ran `raco pkg update --clone` in the wrong folder, and now I can't seem to get it to move to the correct directory.

I tried simply moving the directory, but racket (understandably) didn't know how to handle that, and I tried just deleting the directory, but that didn't work either.

I *could* theoretically uninstall the package and reinstall it. But I have a lot of packages that already depend on it installed, and it would be very annoying to have to uninstall all of them, and reinstall them all again.

Do I have any other options, or am I just doomed to manually uninstalling and reinstalling a lot of packages (or just reinstalling the whole Racket distribution)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can convert a `--clone`ed package back into a regular package. The flag you are looking for is `--lookup`. What you should do is:

```
raco pkg update --lookup <my-package>
cd to/the/desired/dir
raco pkg update --clone <my-package>
```

Note that all `--lookup` does is tell Racket to use the downloaded copy it has, rather than the cloned repo you had it point to. It does *NOT* delete the old cloned repo. So if you no longer want it on your system, you have to remove it yourself.

Additionally, note the use of `raco pkg update` here. Even if you got into the problem by running `raco pkg install --clone ...` in the wrong directory, you still should run `raco pkg update ...` here, because you are only moving where Racket looks to find the package

Finally, you can use `--lookup` and `--clone` at the same time:

```
cd to/the/desired/dir
raco pkg update --lookup --clone <my-package>
```

I should also note that this answer is based on a [similar question from the Racket mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/racket-dev/tZBqLKI8JME/QW0XZwFEBQAJ)